# In framer-motion, how to animate pure data like a number from 0 to 100?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framerjs, framer-motion

How can I animate a pure number from 0 to 100 with a transition config?

```
<motion.div>
  {num}
</motion.div>
```

Comment: You don't, you have to change a value with speed you wan't. You don't need for simple counter any library.

Comment: ...unless it's value of color, width, position etc, then check out docs https://www.framer.com/api/motion/motionvalue

Comment: Thank you, but motionValue can only be set() immediately or tracking an existing style value, can't be animated.

Comment: Define what call you animation when it comes going from 0 to 100? 0 fades out, than 1 fades in...?

Comment: Simply like click a button, then trigger num animation start, which goes from 0 to 100.

Comment: Still sounds like a counter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Framer Motion 2.8 [a new `animate` function](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-function/) was released, which is a good fit for this use case:

```js
import { animate } from "framer-motion";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Counter({ from, to }) {
  const nodeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const node = nodeRef.current;

    const controls = animate(from, to, {
      duration: 1,
      onUpdate(value) {
        node.textContent = value.toFixed(2);
      },
    });

    return () => controls.stop();
  }, [from, to]);

  return <p ref={nodeRef} />;
}

export default function App() {
  return <Counter from={0} to={100} />;
}
```

Note that instead of updating a React state continuously, the DOM is patched manually in my solution to avoid reconciliation overhead.

See [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-counter-wfh4j?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Update: **this will add to your bundle size**. Framer motion has now removed the popmotion dependency so you will need to install + load popmotion seperately

Comment: Isn't the dependency still there? https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/b3c8d88d3b689651f34ba9c266aaf398a6e3b1d2/package.json#L97 It's worth noting though that you should use the transitive dependency, e.g. if you `npm install popmotion` you likely end up with two copies of popmotion in your bundle.

Comment: sorry I misread the framer motion change log : you're correct popmotion is already listed as a dependency, but framer-motion only imports a list of key-value pairs and utility functions,everything else is tree-shaked out. If you wish to use popmotion you should still explicitly install it and understand that there will be additional kb  being added to ur bundle from the import

Comment: @Downgoat Framer Motion 2.8 is out with a newly added utility function for this use case. I've updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: To an extension to this question, can this API be used with variants, such as `staggerChildren` etc?

Answer (score 1):

For those seeking a TypeScript-based approach, including a in view execution.

```
import { animate } from "framer-motion";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

interface CounterProps {
  from: number;
  to: number;
}

const Counter: React.FC<CounterProps> = ({ from, to }) => {
  const nodeRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement | null>(null);
  const [isInView, setIsInView] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const node = nodeRef.current;
    if (!node) return;

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            setIsInView(true);
          }
        });
      },
      { threshold: 0.1 }
    );

    observer.observe(node);

    return () => {
      observer.unobserve(node);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isInView) return;

    const node = nodeRef.current;
    if (!node) return;

    const controls = animate(from, to, {
      duration: 1,
      onUpdate(value) {
        node.textContent = Math.round(value).toString();
      },
    });

    return () => controls.stop();
  }, [from, to, isInView]);

  return (
    <motion.p
      ref={nodeRef}
      initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.1 }}
      animate={isInView ? { opacity: 1, scale: 1 } : {}}
      transition={{ duration: 0.4 }}
    />
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer didn't work for me so I implemented this one here using the animate content part of this page https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/

```
import {motion, useMotionValue, useTransform, animate}  from 'framer-motionn';   

const Counter = ({ from, to, duration }) => {
 const count = useMotionValue(from);
 const rounded = useTransform(count, (latest) => Math.round(latest));

  useEffect(() => {
    const controls = animate(count, to, { duration: duration });
    return controls.stop;
  }, []);

 return <motion.p>{rounded}</motion.p>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I might add this in-case it's useful for anyone.

**Differences compared to above answers**

- Starts animation when component is 100px into the viewport.
- Pretty print numbers (aka rounded, no decimals) and commas.
- Begins slowly and speeds up.
- [LazyMotion](https://www.framer.com/motion/guide-reduce-bundle-size/)

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import { LazyMotion, domAnimation, m, useAnimate, useInView, useMotionValue, useTransform } from "framer-motion";

function ComponentName({ num }) {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const isInView = useInView(ref, {
        once: true,
        margin: "0px 0px -100px 0px"
    });

    const [ _, animate ] = useAnimate();
    const startingValue = useMotionValue(0);

    const currentValue = useTransform(startingValue, (value) => (
        Math.round(value).toLocaleString() + "+")
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isInView) {
        animate(startingValue, num, {
          duration: 5,
          ease: "circIn"
        });
      }
    }, [animate, isInView, num, startingValue]);

    return (
      <LazyMotion features={domAnimation}>
          <m.p ref={ref}>{current}</m.p>
      </LazyMotion>
    );
}
```